Max sum when in each step selecting one addend, then removing last and first element
I have an array. Each iteration, I take an element from the array and add it to a running sum. Then, the first and last element are discarded. I cannot pick an element in the same initial index twice.
How would I find the max sum?
Example test cases
[4, 4, 8, 5, 3, 2] ans = 17, pick index 0, then index 3, then index 2.
[1, 5, 5, 2] ans = 10, pick index 1, then index 2
My solution was dp with memoization, but I hit max recursion depth.
How can the result be found without hitting the max recursion depth?
TIs there perhaps another approach?

Is this happening until the array has no more elements? Or just once? Are you interested  in max sum for each round, or just in the end? Are you not allowed picking the same element twice or the same index ?

You should post your solution even if it fails - perhaps there's a way to limit the amount of recursion that it does.

Simply increase the recursion depth limit?

Sure, but I wanted to know if anyone could come up with a solution that requires less recursion/a better memoization approach

Is the array length always even?

Play it backwards, i.e., inside-out. Always add the two new elements to a max-heap and then move the largest value from the heap to the sum.
from heapq import *

def sumgame_mine(ar):
    heap = []
    n = len(ar)
    sum = 0
    for i in range(n//2, n):
        for j in {i, n-1-i}:
            heappush(heap, -ar[j])
        sum -= heappop(heap)
    return sum

(Python only has min-heap, so I negate the values.)
Testing with Matt's (whose "expand outward" inspired mine) and an array of 1000 random numbers from 0 to 999, both solutions compute the same sum:
381147 283.0 ms  sumgame_Matt
381147   1.4 ms  sumgame_mine

The test code (Attempt This Online!):
import random
from time import time

ar = random.choices(range(1000), k=1000)
for f in sumgame_Matt, sumgame_mine:
    t = time()
    print(f(ar[:]), f'{(time()-t)*1e3:5.1f} ms ', f.__name__)

A variation of my solution, getting the sum of the chosen elements as the sum of all elements minus the unchosen elements:
def sumgame_mine(ar):
    heap = []
    n = len(ar)
    for i in range(n//2, n):
        for j in {i, n-1-i}:
            heappush(heap, -ar[j])
        heappop(heap)
    return sum(ar + heap)

Attempt This Online!

Minor note-  roughly 35% of your time is spent in creating the temporary set {i, n-1-i}. Just unrolling this out to the two heappush statements speeds it up significantly.

@DillonDavis Yeah but then I'd need some other way to handle odd length arrays, and my focus was short code.

Let's say you're playing this game with an N-element array.  On the first turn, you have 2 choices:

Pick the largest element from the start or end, and then play the same game with the N-2 other elements;
Forget about the start and end forever, and pick an element from the inside N-2.  This is like going into the N-2 game with an extra selection at the beginning.

In order to make that choice, you need to know which element you'd get for choice 2.  To figure that out, you need to consider 2 cases for the N-2 game -- either you get an extra selection at the beginning, or you don't.  For the N-4 game you might get 2 extra selections, etc.
To cover all the cases, we can start at the middle element game and then expand outward, calculating a list of best sums in all the cases -- 0 extra guesses, 1 extra guesses, etc., up to size/2 extra guesses.
It's easy to calculate this list for size n if you have the list for size n-2.  The best possible result for k extra guesses is the max of:

The biggest element on the start or end, plus the result of playing n-2 with k guesses;
The result of playing n-2 with k+1 extra guesses; and
If k>=1, the sum of both the start end end elements, plus the result of playing n-2 with k-1 guesses.

This leads to a simple O(N2) algorithm:
def sumgame(ar):
    start = len(ar)//2
    end = len(ar)-start
    if start == end:
        # even number of elements in array
        results = [0]
    else:
        # odd number of elements in array, middle has 1
        results = [ar[start]]

    while start > 0:
        start-=1
        end+=1
        first = ar[start]
        last = ar[end-1]

        # calc result for k=0
        best = max(first, last) + results[0]
        if len(results) > 1:
            best = max(best, results[1])
        newresults = [best]

        # calc rest
        for k in range(1, len(results)+1):
            best = first + last + results[k-1]
            if k < len(results):
                best = max(best, max(first, last) + results[k])
            if k+1 < len(results):
                best = max(best, results[k+1])
            newresults.append(best)
        results = newresults
    
    return results[0]


import heapq

def maximize_sum_with_heap(arr):
    left, right = 0, len(arr) - 1
    iteration_counter = 1
    max_heap = []
    total_sum = 0
    
    while left <= right:
        if left <= right:
            heapq.heappush(max_heap, arr[left])
        if left < right:
            heapq.heappush(max_heap, arr[right])
        
        
        while len(max_heap) > iteration_counter:
            heapq.heappop(max_heap)
        
       
        left += 1
        right -= 1
        iteration_counter += 1
    
    return sum(max_heap)


Please follow the Style guide for Python code. Sketch how the code is guaranteed to meet the requirements - I prefer in the code.

A streamlined version of ajay's and an explanation:
def sumgame__ajay_and_nocomment_1(ar):
    i, j = 0, len(ar)
    picked = []
    while i < j:
        heappush(picked, ar[i])
        i += 1
        if i < j:
            j -= 1
            heappushpop(picked, ar[j])
    return sum(picked)

Each step, we can pick the first or last element before they get removed. Or we can pick both, if we sacrifice a previously picked element. Which we do if there's a smaller one. Put differently, we do pick both, and then discard the smallest picked element, which is either the current first or the last or a previously picked one.
We can also pick neither and instead pick one of the inner elements, but that's equivalent to picking the first or last now and sacrificing it for that inner one later.
One exception is the middle element in case the input array has odd length. Then in the last step, we just pick that element.
We use a heap, which allows efficient insertion and efficient removal of the smallest value.
Same solution written differently:
def sumgame__ajay_and_nocomment_2(ar):
    n = len(ar)
    middle = n // 2
    picked = []
    for first, last in zip(ar[:middle], reversed(ar)):
        heappush(picked, first)
        heappushpop(picked, last)
    return sum(picked) + (ar[middle] if n % 2 else 0)

Optimized version:
def sumgame__ajay_and_nocomment_3(ar):
    heap = []
    heaps = repeat(heap, len(ar))
    lefts = map(heappush, heaps, ar)
    rights = map(heappushpop, heaps, reversed(ar))
    deque(zip(lefts, rights), 0)
    return sum(heap)

A little benchmark with 10000 elements:
  1.9 ± 0.0 ms  sumgame__ajay_and_nocomment_3
  2.0 ± 0.0 ms  sumgame__ajay_and_nocomment_2
  2.3 ± 0.0 ms  sumgame__ajay_and_nocomment_1
  3.9 ± 0.1 ms  sumgame__ajay
  4.7 ± 0.1 ms  sumgame__nocomment_2
  5.1 ± 0.4 ms  sumgame__nocomment_1

Python: 3.12.2 (main, Oct  2 2024, 20:07:08) [GCC 14.2.1 20240910]

Full code (Attempt This Online!):
def sumgame__nocomment_1(ar):
    heap = []
    n = len(ar)
    sum = 0
    for i in range(n//2, n):
        for j in {i, n-1-i}:
            heappush(heap, -ar[j])
        sum -= heappop(heap)
    return sum

def sumgame__nocomment_2(ar):
    heap = []
    n = len(ar)
    for i in range(n//2, n):
        for j in {i, n-1-i}:
            heappush(heap, -ar[j])
        heappop(heap)
    return sum(ar + heap)

def sumgame__ajay_and_nocomment_1(ar):
    i, j = 0, len(ar)
    picked = []
    while i < j:
        heappush(picked, ar[i])
        i += 1
        if i < j:
            j -= 1
            heappushpop(picked, ar[j])
    return sum(picked)

def sumgame__ajay_and_nocomment_2(ar):
    n = len(ar)
    middle = n // 2
    picked = []
    for first, last in zip(ar[:middle], reversed(ar)):
        heappush(picked, first)
        heappushpop(picked, last)
    return sum(picked) + (ar[middle] if n % 2 else 0)

def sumgame__ajay_and_nocomment_3(ar):
    heap = []
    heaps = repeat(heap, len(ar))
    lefts = map(heappush, heaps, ar)
    rights = map(heappushpop, heaps, reversed(ar))
    deque(zip(lefts, rights), 0)
    return sum(heap)

def sumgame__ajay(arr):
    left, right = 0, len(arr) - 1
    iteration_counter = 1
    max_heap = []
    total_sum = 0
    
    while left <= right:
        if left <= right:
            heapq.heappush(max_heap, arr[left])
        if left < right:
            heapq.heappush(max_heap, arr[right])
        
        
        while len(max_heap) > iteration_counter:
            heapq.heappop(max_heap)
        
       
        left += 1
        right -= 1
        iteration_counter += 1
    
    return sum(max_heap)

funcs = [
    sumgame__nocomment_1,
    sumgame__nocomment_2,
    sumgame__ajay,
    sumgame__ajay_and_nocomment_1,
    sumgame__ajay_and_nocomment_2,
    sumgame__ajay_and_nocomment_3,
]

from heapq import *
import heapq
from itertools import repeat
from collections import deque
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
from itertools import product
import sys
import random

# Correctness
for n in range(9990, 10001):
    ar = random.choices(range(10000), k=10000)
    expect = funcs[0](ar)
    for f in funcs:
        result = f(ar)
        if result != expect:
            print('FAIL:', f.__name__, expect, result)

# Speed
times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):5.1f} ± {stdev(ts):3.1f} ms '
for _ in range(100):
    random.shuffle(funcs)
    for f in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: f(ar), number=1) / 1
        times[f].append(t)
for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)

print('\nPython:', sys.version)

